# SQL After Delete Trigger has Null values in the Deleted Pseudotable?

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

Im trying to make this trigger work when trying to delete a record. The way it is suposed to work is, when someone tries to delete a record it rollbacks and inserts an audit record to TbAudit table which by the way, all columns have a NOT NULL constraint. However, turns out it wont do it, because for some reason I dont understand when I try to delete a record it will display the message and rollback BUT all my variables within the select statement are getting NULL values even though Im pulling them directly from the "deleted" table. Please help.

```
USE BdPlan
GO
CREATE TRIGGER TrAudit
   ON  Plan.TPlan
   AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @IdPlan = int,
        @IdEmployee int,
        @Month int,
        @Year int

ROLLBACK
PRINT 'CANT DELETE RECORDS'

-- All variables are getting NULL

SELECT  @IdPlan = D.IdPlan,            
        @IdEmployee = D.IdEmployee ,   
        @Month = D.Month,              
        @Year = D.Year                 

FROM    deleted AS D

INSERT INTO BdAudit.dbo.TbAudit
           VALUES
               (
               @IdPlan,
               @IdEmployee,
               @Month,
               @Year,
               SUSER_NAME(),
               GETDATE()
               )
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there may be problems with this approach:

- you are trying to access the `DELETED` pseudotable after the transaction has been rolled back - it will have zero rows after the rollback (see below)
- your trigger only attempts to deal with a single row deletion - it should be able to handle multi row deletes

It is also noted that inserting directly into the Audit table from the Deleted pseudotable before `ROLLBACK` will of course roll the audit data back as well.

[From here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/04/13/60174.aspx) it is apparent you can cache the data to be audited in a `@Temporary` table variable, then do the `ROLLBACK` (which doesn't undo the @Temp table), and then do the Audit insertion:

```
ALTER trigger d_foo ON FOO AFTER DELETE
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE
    (
        ID INT, 
        -- Obviously add all your fields go here
    );

    INSERT INTO @Temp(ID)
        SELECT ID FROM DELETED;

    ROLLBACK TRAN;

    insert into fooaudit(id)
        select id from @Temp;
END;
```

[Simplified SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/813c1/2) with multiple row deletion.

To confirm, the `DELETED` pseudotable contains zero rows after a ROLLBACK in a trigger, as this [modified Fiddle demonstrates](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4853d2/1).

Comment: Do be careful with using a ROLLBACK inside a trigger. If your outer code has an explicit transaction you will get an exception because there will be no transaction to rollback or commit. I would prefer to use RAISERROR so the calling application knows something happened and you don't get mismatched transactions.